# PHP - Выборка из нескольких баз данных

Tags: php, mysql

Перерыл все, что можно, но внятного ответа так и не нашел.
Задача в следующем. Есть 7 баз данных на одном сервере. В базах - таблицы с одинаковым именем (bn), а в таблице - столбец, так же с одинаковым именем во всех базах (sn). 
Необходимо в одном mysql запросе выбрать ТОЛЬКО уникальные значения из всех семи столбцов и вывести полученные данные на странице.

Например:

> база: BD1 - таблица: BN - столбец: SN - содержимое столбца: дом, овощ,
>   дом, колесо, дом, овощ 
> база: BD2 - таблица: BN - столбец: SN  -
>   содержимое столбца:  овощ, кукла, дом, колесо, колесо 
> база: BD3 -
>   таблица: BN - столбец: SN  - содержимое столбца:  кукла, дом, дом,
>   овощ 
> и т.д.

На выходе:
дом, овощ, кукла, колесо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: скорей всего запрос будет, что-то типо такого `SELECT * FROM db1.bn, db2.bn` и т.д через запятую все нужные `BD`, если запрос сработает, то для уникальных значений используйте `DISTINCT`

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть хотя бы схематичный, но полный запрос. К сожалению, в предложенном виде он не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На тестовом сервере создал БД `db1`, `db2`, `db3` в каждой есть таблица `tb`, В таблицах столбец `sn`. Для вывода всех уникальных значений

```
SELECT db1.tb.sn AS SN FROM db1.tb
UNION
SELECT db2.tb.sn AS SN FROM db2.tb
UNION
SELECT db3.tb.sn AS SN FROM db3.tb
```

за счет `union` мы объединяем указанные столбцы в один, а так же убираем повторные значения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все заработало и понятно, почему :) А если убрать задачу выбирать уникальные значения и оставить только перебор столбца во всех базах, что нужно изменить? Например, как посчитать, сколько раз повторяется слово "дом"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM database.table
```

Можно указать базу данных как префикс.